# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1 + 1/2 + 1/3+\cdots+1/2n- \ln n$

Tags: real-analysis

I know the proof of  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \ln n = \gamma$$ but how do I use that proof to find the value of the limit above.

Comment: I guess I want to know if the limit with still be a function of gamma or am I looking to get a specific number.

Comment: @Dr.MV The one in the body is a related limit that the author knows. The question is asking the one in the title.

Comment: MathNoob.  I was replying to a comment made earlier that has been deleted.

Comment: I continue to hope that my answers are at least _simpler_ than some others. (See below.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It took me many years to learn that if I write $\log 2$, some people think I mean something other than $\log_e 2$.  Now the World has finally caused me to start writing $\ln 2$, not because I like it but because I fear being misunderstood.  I noticed after posting my answer below that I had done it that way. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 7):

Hint:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} = \log (2n) + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right). $$
Therefore
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} - \log n = \log 2 + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right). $$

Comment: That's more than a hint!

Comment: ... and that should suffice!

Comment: Ok, this actually helps out alot.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(n)=1+1/2+\dots+1/n - \log n$. Then you can write the terms of your sequence as
$$
f(2n)+(\log(2n)-\log n)=f(2n)+\log2
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \cdots + \frac 1 {2n} -\ln n \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big(\  \underbrace{1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \cdots + \frac 1 {2n} -\ln(2n)}_{\text{This part approaches $\gamma$.}}\  \Big) + \ln 2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(n)=1+{1\over2}+{1\over3}+\cdots+{1\over n}-\ln n$.  The integral comparison test that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)$ exists also gives upper and lower bounds:

$$g(n)-{1\over n}\lt\gamma\lt g(n)$$

so to get $k$ digits of $\gamma$ it suffices to compute $g(2\cdot10^k)$.  This is a little like using the series $1-{1\over3}+{1\over5}-{1\over7}+\cdots$ to get digits of $\pi$, but it works in principle.